# Plural von "Skript" und "Tumor"

Tags: grammar, etymology, noun

Wieder einmal eine Frage, da mich mein sonst untrügliches Sprachgefühl getäuscht hat.

Meine Kommilitonen verwenden *Skripten* als Plural von *Skript* (etwa im "Skriptenserver"). [Der Duden sagt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Skript):

> Plural: die Skripte[n] und Skripts

Ich interpretiere das so, dass beides geht. In Bayern und NRW scheint *Skripten* üblicher zu sein; aus meiner ostdeutschen Heimat kenne ich nur *Skripte*, ähnlich zu *Stuhl*, *Stühle*. Lässt sich darüber mehr sagen (regionale Verteilung, "richtigeres", etc), oder ist das nun einfach so?

Ein größeres Problem habe ich noch mit *Tumor*. [Der Duden sagt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tumor):

> Plural: die Tumoren, umgangssprachlich auch: Tumore

*Tumoren* geht meinem Sprachgefühl nun komplett gegen den Strich, klingt wie Dativ. Hat der Duden recht, wenn er meiner Muttersprache und damit gleichsam meiner Mutter "Umgangssprache" attestiert? Nach welchem Prinzip legt sich das fest? Und wie re-trainiert man sein Ohr, damit derart "richtiges" nicht mehr falsch klingt? Und ist Deutsch nicht irgendwie ziemlich irregulär?

Comment: Ob das Deutsche sehr irregulär ist, hat damit nicht so viel zu tun, es geht hier ja eher um den Umgang mit Fremdwörtern, und dazu noch solchen, die in einem akademischen Umfeld gebraucht werden. Da ist wahrscheinlichlich die Tendenz, Formen zu erhalten, die sich aus der Ursprungssprache ableiten, größer.

Comment: Dass der Wandel nicht aufzuhalten ist, erkennt man aber schon daran, dass der Singular "Skript" für eine Vorlesungsmitschrift das Wort "Skriptum" schon fast verdrängt hat ;)

Comment: Es gibt das Skript(um) als Mitschrift und das Skript als eingebettetes Programm. Für ersteres ist "Skripten" als Plural gebräuchlich, für das andere "Skripts" oder "Skripte". Welcher Plural für die Bedeutung "Drehbuch" verwendet wird, die das Skript nach dem Englischen zunehmend auch bei uns bekommt, weiß ich allerdings nicht; wohl eher "Skripts". "Tumoren" lautet die Mehrzahl von Tumor vielleicht deswegen, weil sie im Lateinischen "tumores" heißt.

Answer (score 3):

### Skript

Ich glaube, dass der Plural von der Bedeutung abhängt:

**gedrucktes Dokument**
Ein Skript ist ein in geringer Auflage vervielfältigtes Dokument. Etwa ein Vorlesungsskript (früher »Skriptum«), oder die Vorlage für ein Theaterstück oder einen Film:

> Das Skript - Die **Skripten**
>   »Die **Skripten** für die aktuellen Vorlesungen müssen Sie bitte selbst ausdrucken.«

**Computerprogramm**
Ein Skript ist eine bestimmte Form eines Computerprogramms. (Ein Skript wird meist nicht kompiliert, sondern interpretiert):

> Das Skript - Die **Skripte**
>   »Nadine hat gestern vier **Skripte** getestet und optimiert.«

### Tumor

Ich (geboren in Graz, seit 1997 in Wien) muss zugeben, die Mehrzahlform »Tumoren« noch nie gehört zu haben. Also habe ich im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch, das amtliche Wörterbuch für die in Österreich gesprochene Varietät der deutschen Sprache) nachgesehen, und dort sind beide Mehrzahlformen gleichberechtigt angeführt, ohne eine Empfehlung für eine der beiden Formen abzugeben, oder sie auf eine andere Weise zu werten.