# Why is the Genitiv "des Tumors" and not "des Tumoren"?

Tags: genitive

Off the back of [Why is it "Tumoren" and not "Tumore"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50586/why-is-it-tumoren-and-not-tumore), why is the Genitiv "des Tumors" and not "des Tumoren"?

> [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tumor): der Tumor; Genitiv: des Tumors, Plural: die Tumoren, umgangssprachlich auch: Tumore

My understanding is that to form the Genitiv from the Nominativ *der oder das* it is typically *Substantiv + s*, i.e.

> der Vater --> des Vaters
>   das Hotel --> des Hotels

albeit sometimes with an '*es*'

> das Jahr --> des Jahres

except when the Plural ending is '*en*'

> der Therapeut, die Therapeuten --> des Therapeuten

So since the plural of *der Tumor* is *die Tumoren*, why is the Genitiv "des Tumors" and not "des Tumoren"?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question. You say, that your rule of thumb only applies in the *typical* case. So, what if the answer to your question was just: "This is not a typical case". Of course, this would hardly satisfy you. But what kind of answer would that be, that satisfies you? Would you be satisfied by a bunch of counterexamples to your rule of thumb, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

Maskuline Nomen mit *n*-Plural können zwei verschiedenen Deklinationsklassen angehören: der **schwachen**, die *-(e)n* im gesamten Singular mit Ausnahme des Nominativ haben, und der **gemischten**, die im Genitiv Singular die Endung *-(e)s* haben.

> **schwach**: Experte, Herr, Junge, Kollege, Kunde, Name, Pilot, Soldat, …
>
> **gemischt**: -tor, Schmerz, Staat, Strahl, …

Answer (score 1):

There's another representative of the *gemischte Deklination* you're certainly familiar with: *der Doktor; des Doktors // die Doktoren*. And if you're willing to forget the additional -e- for a second: *der Schmerz; des Schmerzes // die Schmerzen*. A neuter one: *das Elektron; des Elektrons // die Elektronen*. Mind that none of these are an exception, but the rule.